# Is there a way to express a closed form for a partial derivative of this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Here's the relation:

if $n\ge j:$ then
$$ \sigma(n,j,d) = d \cdot\left( \log j-\sigma\left(\frac{n}{j}, 1+d, d \right)\right)+\sigma(n, j+d, d )$$

And here's the terminating condition

if $n < j$ then
$$ \sigma(n,j,d) = 0$$

Now, here's what I'm interested in:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial d}\sigma(n,j,d)=\text{ ?}$$

for some fixed positive whole numbers $n$ and $j$, and $d$ a real number such that $0<d\le 1$.

Is there a way to express this in a closed form?

(I hope this was the right tag)